# Is this Distance between 2 Pairs code right? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a program that gives me the distance between any two points given their ordered pairs.

I think I may have the code, but I need someone to check and make sure it's correct.

```
oInput = ["9.5 7.5", "10.2 19.1", "9.7 10.2"]

inp = [(float(j[0]), float(j[1])) for j in [i.split() for i in oInput]]

min_distance = float('infinity')
min_pair = None

length = len(inp)
for i in xrange(length):
    for j in xrange(i+1, length):
        point1 = inp[i]
        point2 = inp[j]

        if math.hypot(point1[0] - point2[0], point1[1] - point2[0]) < min_distance:
            min_pair = [point1, point2]
```

Comment: *"I need someone to check and make sure it's correct"* - why? Have you considered *testing it?!*

Answer (score 1):

So first of all you use wrong indices here:

```
math.hypot(point1[0] - point2[0], point1[1] - point2[0]) # current, wrong
math.hypot(point1[0] - point2[0], point1[1] - point2[1]) # right
```

Second, this program does not what you described, it will yield pairs of points that are closer than a given `min_distance`.

Comment: @L.Nohr sry I used the wrong comment format. Use # instead //